# Using Angular animation for images slider

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use angular animation to make an image slider, and images are changing as I want.
But the problem is that the changing is done really fast (sudden change of image), and I'd like to make it slower and as if an image is taking place of previous one. (I don't know a lot about jquery and animations)

my code:

ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {
  trigger,
  transition,
  query,
  style,
  animate,
  group
} from "@angular/animations";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-slider',
  animations: [
    trigger("slider", [
      transition(
        ":increment",
        group([
          query(":enter", [
            style({
              left: "100%"
            }),
            animate("0.5s ease-out", style("*")) //I also tried changing the time and nothing changed
          ]),
          query(":leave", [
            animate(
              "0.5s ease-out",
              style({
                left: "-100%"
              })
            )
          ])
        ])
      ),
      transition(
        ":decrement",
        group([
          query(":enter", [
            style({
              left: "-100%"
            }),
            animate("0.5s ease-out", style("*"))
          ]),
          query(":leave", [
            animate(
              "0.5s ease-out",
              style({
                left: "100%"
              })
            )
          ])
        ])
      )
    ])
  ],
  templateUrl: './slider.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./slider.component.css']
})
export class SliderComponent implements OnInit {
  recImage:any

  //to store the images
  private _images: string[] = [];
  //used for navigating between the images
  selectedIndex: number = 0;
  //to store the main image
  MainImage: any;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._images = ["../../../../assets/MAIN.jpg","../../../../assets/d7d25-a.jpg","../../../../assets/MAIN.jpg"];


  }
  ngAfterViewInit(){
    setInterval(() => {
      this.next()
    }, 3000);
  }

  get images() {
    return [this._images[this.selectedIndex]];
  }
  //to go to previous image
  previous() {
    this.selectedIndex = Math.max(this.selectedIndex - 1, 0);
  }
  //to go to next image
  next() {
    if(this.selectedIndex == this._images.length - 1){
      this.selectedIndex = 0
    }
    this.selectedIndex = Math.min(
      this.selectedIndex + 1,
      this._images.length - 1
    );
  }
}
```

html:

```
<section class="sizing-slider">
    <section  class="bg-image" style="margin-top:-20px"> // I need these 2 sections for design purposes
         <div class="slide" [@slider]="selectedIndex" style="text-align: center;  justify-content: center;" *ngFor="let image of images">
            <img [src]="image" style="width:100%;" class="slidedown" />
            </div> 
      </section>
    </section>
```

Please help me letting the change of images appear better (maybe fading or a slow replacing)
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the library https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-slick-carousel and it worked fine.